# Program to eject cash drawer with network Epson printer

Tags: payment, thermal-printer, epson, pos

I just created a solution to a problem that I've come across and after google-ing, couldn't find an easy answer. We have computers that are connected to networked Epson thermal docket printers for POS, which are connected to cash drawers.

Epson have a utility that allows you to send ASCII codes to their printers (Send data tool - senddat.exe can be downloaded here: https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=single_soft&cid=5027&pcat=3&pid=37). Once you figure out the correct cash drawer codes (http://keyhut.com/popopen4.htm) you can then write a simple batch file similar to below:

@echo off

TITLE Cash Drawer Ejector!

echo Please ensure it is safe for the cash drawer to open!

pause

[may need file path]senddat.exe [cash drawer code].txt [IP of Epson printer connected to cash drawer]

off

Hope this can help others in a similar situation! The text in the command window isn't necessary to make this work, I just wanted to add a prompt for staff members.

Comment: What you have you tried? Is the drawer connected via RS-232 or RS-485

Answer (score 1):

You‘ll need the directory if they aren’t in the same one. Here’s an example if the exe is on the desktop:

```
@echo off
TITLE Cash Drawer Ejector!
echo Please ensure it is safe for the cash drawer to open!
pause
%userprofile%/Desktop/senddat.exe 
%userprofile%/Desktop/27,112,0,50,250.txt 
Rem IP of Epson printer connected to cash drawer
Echo It is now open!
Pause
Off
```

Comment: Good example, should also post some example of the information the codes the OP is asking for which I believe is specific to possibly that EPSON printer / model family but ehy whatev